# Issues with cmake + shared library on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, shared-libraries

I am currently developing a C++ library, and I am using `cmake` as build system. I am new to cmake, however I was able to set it up so it successfully finds external libraries and eventually creates my library as shared lib.

To test the library, I've created a very minimal test program (main.cc), which links against the library. The test program also successfully compiles, and I can run the program and use my library.

**However**, when ending the program, the program crashes in some call to `free` in my code, and `valgrind` also reveals several invalid frees. I have analyzed the problem, and I can see that some of the affected `struct`s contains garbage, instead of beeing properly (zero-)initialized. However the code does not match this, and I fail to find the root cause.

It turns out that when I do not create a shared library, but instead create an executable with cmake directly, everything runs well, and valgrind will show exactly zero errors.

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(cex)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set (CEX_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (CEX_VERSION_MINOR 0)
set (CEX_VERSION_PATCH 0)

# configure a header file to pass some of the CMake settings
# to the source code

configure_file (
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CexConfig.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/cex/cex_config.h"
  )

# add more cmake rules (for libevent & libevhtp & libz)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

# Find mandatory libraries libevent + libevhtp

find_package(LibEvent REQUIRED)
list(APPEND LIBCEX_EXTERNAL_LIBS ${LIBEVENT_LIBRARIES})
list(APPEND package_deps LibEvent)

find_package(LibEvhtp REQUIRED)
list(APPEND LIBCEX_EXTERNAL_LIBS ${LIBEVHTP_LIBRARIES})
list(APPEND package_deps LibEvhtp)

# Find optional libraries openssl + zlib

if(NOT CEX_DISABLE_SSL)
    find_package(OpenSSL)
    if(OPENSSL_FOUND)
        add_definitions(-DCEX_WITH_SSL)
        list(APPEND LIBCEX_EXTERNAL_LIBS OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)
        list(APPEND package_deps OpenSSL)
    endif()
endif()

if(NOT CEX_DISABLE_Z)
   find_package(LibZ)
   if(LIBZ_FOUND)
      add_definitions(-DCEX_WITH_ZLIB)
      list(APPEND LIBCEX_EXTERNAL_LIBS ${LIBZ_LIBRARIES})
      list(APPEND package_deps LibZ)
   endif()
endif()

# add project headers

include_directories(include)
include_directories(include/cex)

# add project sources

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cc")

# generate the library

#add_library(cex SHARED ${SOURCES})
add_executable(cex ${SOURCES} "main.cc")

# compiler options & dependencies

target_compile_options(cex PRIVATE -std=c++11)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(cex PUBLIC ${LIBCEX_EXTERNAL_LIBS})

install(TARGETS cex DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h*")
```

And my project tree is like:

```
+ build
|      \
|       + libcex.dylib
+ cmake                      // FindLibEvent, FindLibZ, FindLibEvhtp
+ include
|        \
|         + cex
|         |    \
|         |     + *hpp       // all project headers
|         + cex.hpp
+ src
|    \
|     *cc                    // all project source files
+ CMakeLists.txt
+ main.cc
```

When using the shared library, I will compile the test program with this:

```
clang -std=c++11 -I./include -I./include/cex main.cc -I/usr/local/ssl/include -L./build -lcex -L/usr/local/ssl/lib/ -lssl -lc++ -o serv
```

Output of the test program when using directly compiled executable w/o library:

```
> ./cex
allocating empty config [NULL]
allocating empty config [NULL]
end of program, freeing now
--
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
--
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
```

Output when using test program + shared library:

```
> ./cex
allocating empty config [NULL]
allocating empty config [NULL]
end of program, freeing now
--
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
free [NULL]
--
free [UH��]����fD]
free [UH��SPH������H��H�[]�:�]
free [NULL]
free [�&��]
free [UH��]�6]
free [NULL]
free [UH��SPH���R���H��H�[]��}]
free [UH��]�6]
serv(1832,0x7fffad967340) malloc: *** error for object 0x10742d720: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Valgrind will be of no real help:

```
==450== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==450==    at 0x1000ABB6D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:533)
==450==    by 0x1000C48FB: cex::Server::Config::~Config() (in /Development/httpsrv/build/libcex.dylib)
==450==    by 0x100000E7E: main (in ./cex)
==450==  Address 0x1000c1720 is in the Text segment of /Development/httpsrv/build/libcex.dylib
==450==    at 0x1000C1720: cex::Server::~Server() (in /Development/httpsrv/build/libcex.dylib)
==450==
==450== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==450==    at 0x1000ABB6D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:533)
==450==    by 0x1000C4908: cex::Server::Config::~Config() (in /Development/httpsrv/build/libcex.dylib)
==450==    by 0x100000E7E: main (in ./cex)
==450==  Address 0x1000c1730 is in the Text segment of /Development/httpsrv/build/libcex.dylib
==450==    at 0x1000C1730: cex::Server::~Server() (in /Development/httpsrv/build/libcex.dylib)
==450==
==450== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==450==    at 0x1000ABB6D: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:533)
==450==    by 0x1000C4922: cex::Server::Config::~Config() (in /Development/httpsrv/build/libcex.dylib)
==450==    by 0x100000E7E: main (in ./cex)
==450==  Address 0x100294a20 is in the Data segment of /Development/httpsrv/build/libcex.dylib
```

Output of `otool -L` looks correct:

```
> otool -L cex
cex:
    /Development/httpsrv/build/libcex.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.0.0)
```

What could possibly be causing this issue/difference between direct executable & shared library? I think I am correctly linking the libraries, so I don't know how there can be a difference? :s

Comment: There is no issue in CMake code. It is library's **source code** (C++ one) which is written wrongly. There is so much possibilities to write a wrong code, so without the code itself your question is almost useless.

Comment: I am not claiming that CMake itself has an issue. But as I said, if I compile the complete executable with all source files from the library directly, and said executable does not have any issues, how will there be an error in the library source files?
I rather think it is some kind of library generation/linking issue.

Comment: `said executable does not have any issues, how will there be an error in the library source files?` - **Absence of an error** observed in one situation **doesn't mean** that source code is **correct**. It is very possible that another situation will reveal the error in the source code. Exactly what you have when compile the executable as a library. Well, it is *possible* that your source code is correct, and you just use improper linking flags or so. You ask us, what the proper linking flags are, but it is **dependent on your code**. Again, we need to see your code for being able to help you.